# Reset IgnoreCollision in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character do a drop attack in `Unity` where I want to ignore the collision detection of `boxCollider2D` for the moment when character & an enemy collide, then undo the ignore. So far the ignore collision is working but it's not reverting back to detect. So after the first successful drop attack my character can pass through the enemy instead of colliding. Here's my code below,

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anm;
private Collider2D coll;
private enum State {idle, running, jumping, attacking, falling, hurt}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        Enemy enemy = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();

        if (state == State.falling && anm.GetBool("dropAtk")) {  // hurt enemy if drop attack
            enemy.Hurt();
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>(), true);
        } else {  // take damange
            if (other.gameObject.transform.position.x > transform.position.x) {
                PlayerHurt("right");
            } else {
                PlayerHurt("left");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        if (coll.IsTouchingLayers(ground)) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), GetComponent<Collider2D>(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I re-enable collision detection by turning off the `IgnoreCollision` when character hits the ground? I'm a novice in Unity.

Comment: Thing is that if you ignore the collision you probably won't get the `OnCollisionExit2D` ...

Comment: So how can I fix this without `OnCollisionExit2D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you get the idea

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(state==dropattck)
        {
            ChangeTrigger(player, true);
            if(player.transform.position.y<floorvalue/*check your floor value*/)
            {
                transform.position.y = floorvalue;
            }
        }else
        {
            ChangeTrigger(player, false);
        }
    }
    public void ChangeTrigger(GameObject obj,bool tf)
    {
        if(obj.GetComponent<Collider2D>().isTrigger!=tf)
            obj.GetComponent<Collider2D>().isTrigger = tf;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's working exactly how I wanted. Just a small note, I had to set the `enemy.Hurt()` on `OnTriggerEnter2D` method since now the character's collision is on trigger during the drop attack.

Answer (score 0):

a solution that comes to mind is to bound the position on the y axis and then temporarily set your collider to trigger. you bound the y so the player doesn't fall through the floor
otherwise you can check when your animation ends and set the collider back to detecting

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, I tried using trigger on enemy but it makes it falling. Never thought of bounding the y since I'm new in Unity. Can you show me the codes for the suggestion you provided?

Answer (score 0):

to do a general reset you can turn either of the relevant gameobjects off+on
source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html